# Why Python doesn't raise an exception if seeking and reading past the end of a file?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I was writing unit tests to see what would happen if my code was seeking and reading past the end of a binary file opened in read only and binary mode (`rb` mode).

I was pretty sure an exception would be raised in that case, but it is not (tested on Python 3.x):

```
>>> fname = r"c:\tmp\test.bin"
>>> os.path.getsize(fname)
60
>>> f = open(fname, "rb")
>>> f.seek(100)
100
>>> f.tell()
100
>>> f.read()
b''
>>>
```

Questions:

- Why is this behavior allowed (inherited from C?)? I understand the behavior for files in write mode, but not in read-only mode.
- Is reading past the end of a file considered an undefined behavior? Does it return always an empty `bytes`? Is it implementation defined?

**Edit**: changed mode from `r+b` to `rb` where the behavior is still the same.

Comment: @Alik: Those docs are not correct for Py3; they describe it wrapping `fread`, when in Py3, [they moved to using the raw OS I/O interfaces, not the C standard buffered I/O interfaces](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase), with all buffering implemented in Python directly.

Comment: @ShadowRanger oops, I didn't pay attention to python version OP uses.

Comment: `+` added to any of `r`, `w`, `a` file mode specifies, that the file will be opened in read-write mode. Binary read-only mode is `rb`, not `r+b`. A nice table with filemodes on this page:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Comment: @Nikita: Ok ,thank you for your comment, I didn't know. I edited the question with `rb` mode rather than `r+b`. The behavior is still the same.

Answer (score 3):

Your question asks about read mode, but your code demonstrates read-write mode. It is not an error to seek past the end of a writable file, since performing a subsequent write will result in a [**sparse file**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) on filesystems that support it (and zero-fill until the new write on filesystems that don't).

Comment: Could you elaborate on "read-write mode"? I really thought that `r+b` meant "read **only** and binary mode" (I also tried with `rb` to be sure). Am I wrong? Trying to write to the file raise a `io.UnsupportedOperation: write` exception.

Comment: @Neitsa: Python follows C's `fopen(3)` flags where possible. `"r+"` opens an existing file in read-write mode. Read-only and binary is just `"rb"`.

Comment: oh ok, damn... thank you for the precision. I also tried with `rb` then, but the behavior is still the same, I still can go past the end of the file and read which is quite nonsensical to me.